# Trying to add an A Record to SoftLayer DNS using REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I started with using URL with method POST

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createARecord/1914686

1914686 is id for the domain I am trying to add the A Record to.

The content sent is:

```
{
    "parameters" :
    [
       {
         "host" : "dsn-t01",
         "data" : "127.0.0.1",
         "ttl"   : 86400
       }
    ]
  }
```

I am getting RC 500, MSG is "Internal Server Error"
CONTENT sent back is "{"error":"Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please try the answer posted in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683735/creating-a-dns-a-record-using-rest-api-createobject

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/1914686/createARecord

Method: Post
{  
   "parameters":[  
      "dsn-t01",
      "127.0.0.1",
      86400
   ]
}
```

Some important links:

- [SoftLayer_Dns_Domain::createARecord](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createARecord)
- [Rest SoftLayer](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest)