# Creating a DNS A Record using REST API createObject

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I couldn't get `createARecord` to work, so I am trying to use `createObject`.

The URL I am using with GET method.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/createObject
```

The content sent is:

```
      {
    "parameters" :
    [
       {
         "domainId" : "1914686",
         "host" : "dsn-t01",
         "data" : "127.0.0.1",
         "type" : "a",
         "minimum" : undef,
         "retry" : undef,
         "mxPriority" : undef,
         "expire" : undef,
         "responsiblePerson" : undef,
         "id" : undef,
         "ttl"   : 900
       }
    ]
  }
```

> The RC is 500, MSG is "Internal Server Error", the content is
>   "{"error":"Invalid modification structure received.  Expected a
>   skeleton of
>   \'SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord\'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}"

I am not having much success with these REST APIs.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please the following POST request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/createObject.json
```

Method: POST

Json payload:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "domainId": 1769988,
      "data": "127.0.0.1",
      "host": "@",
      "type": "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/createObject)